# How can I host asp.net core application in in-proc in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to host the asp.net core application and for that I tried Nowin as it is given in Documentation, But even Nowin creates the another process names MyProject.exe. 
I want to install IIS in In proccess of app pool instead of creating the different process(Kestrel). Second thing is I use default project template of aspnet core and commented use Kestrel and added Nowin as given in samples. It still creates the new process. The reason I need it to be in same process because Performance monitoring tool I use (NewRelic) does not yet support Kestrel. If I create new project in mvc 5, Empty template and then add aspnewcore nuget packages, It comes till controller, But when It goes to razor it gives error(It works perfect with return Json). Can you help me to know whether it is issue or not? If it is not issue, How can I achieve it? Which type of project I should create?

Error in old website project with aspnet core nuget.

One or more compilation failures occurred:
4nut20vs.g5q(10,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
4nut20vs.g5q(11,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
4nut20vs.g5q(12,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
4nut20vs.g5q(15,36): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ViewFeatures' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
4nut20vs.g5q(16,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
4nut20vs.g5q(18,86): error CS1980: Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
4nut20vs.g5q(18,86): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
4nut20vs.g5q(18,45): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
4nut20vs.g5q(43,16): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'..........

Comment: asp.net core 2.2 supports [`in-process` hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#in-process-hosting-model). the asp.net core app runs in the same process as its IIS worker process. This removes the performance penalty of proxying requests over the loopback adapter when using the out-of-process hosting model.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to host ASP.NET Core in process with IIS. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis for more details.

> The reason I need it to be in same process because Performance monitoring tool I use (NewRelic) does not yet support Kestrel.

Sounds like the NewRelic support you're using is for System.Web based applications. Does it support profiling a managed exe?

Comment: Yes it does support, but the problem is it creates two processes, One apppool process and another Kestrel

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I was asking how the new relic plugin works not about the fact that ASP.NET Core runs out of process.